# javascript form validation not doing anything

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

i am trying to ensure an in put the contents of an input field is within an allowable number of character and if it is not print out an error message after the input field. the bellow js is contained in an external js file.

```
    function validateForm()
    {
        var err_msg = getElementById('feedback_msg_first_name').value;
        var first_name = getElementById('first_name').value;
        if(first_name.length < 2)
        {
            err_msg.innerHTML = 'first name cannot contain less than 2 characters';
            return false;
        }
        if(first_name.length > 20)
        {
            err_msg.innerHTML = 'first name cannot contain more than 20 characters';
            err_msg.style.color = 'red';
        }
    }
```

The basic markup

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="client_form_val.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="register"  name="register" action="includes/register.inc.php" method="post" onsubmit ="return validateForm();">
    <label class="label">First Name:</label>        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" /><br />
    <span id="feedback_msg_first_name"></span>
```

the form is simply submitting without anything happening. where an I going wrong? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your function isn't wrapped in script tags

Comment: @AaronFowler You missed the sentence with _the bellow js is contained in an external js file_

Comment: This isn't checking anything on submission. Seems to be trying to check on keyup of the input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following http://jsfiddle.net/VL7dc/2/

Rather than explaining where your going wrong, think you need to try and understand why this works and your doesnt.

```
  function validateForm() {
        var err_msg = document.getElementById('feedback_msg_first_name');
        var first_name = document.getElementById('first_name').value;

        if(first_name.length < 2) {
            err_msg.innerHTML = 'first name cannot contain less than 2 characters';
            return false;
        } else {
            err_msg.innerHTML = '';
        }
        if(first_name.length > 20)
        {
            err_msg.innerHTML = 'first name cannot contain more than 20 characters';
            err_msg.style.color = 'red';
        }
    }
```

Comment: now am really confused. i copied that code and still doesn't work and it works on js fiddle

Comment: nevermind working now thanks very munch i just was missing the else statements.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function when keyup event is fired in form. As a result when a user start typing his/her name after typing a single character this will show the error message.

Instead of calling the function when keyup event is fired, call the function when some button click happens (When the whole first name is typed).

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to do document.getElementById. Firebug is giving errors on that

Answer (score 0):

Getting errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined
```

When you fix the missing documents you get this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
```

Reason for the second is this

```
var err_msg = getElementById('feedback_msg_first_name').value;  <-- string
err_msg.innerHTML = 'first name cannot contain less than 2 characters';  <--performing innerHTML on string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 function validateForm()
{
    var err_msg = document.getElementById('feedback_msg_first_name');
    var first_name = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    if(first_name.length < 2)
    {
        err_msg.innerHTML = 'first name cannot contain less than 2 characters';
        return false;
    }
    if(first_name.length > 20)
    {
        err_msg.innerHTML = 'first name cannot contain more than 20 characters';
        err_msg.style.color = 'red';
    }
}
```